# How to update a final table based on multiple tables in MS Access?

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, datatables

So I am making a database where the user is required to essentially do a checklist so I have multiple tables that corresponds to this. For example: User table, Inventory table, Store details etc each table having its own primary key. I have created forms that will individually add records to each table and essentially forming the checklist with date records as to when this was done.

I want to then basically create a report of that specific checklist performed by that specific user at that date - basically printing a report that the checklist was completed. I was thinking of making a new table that basically contains the primary key IDs of the User, inventory and store table to consolidate all the data inputted on the forms by user. So question is how do I get the final table to also update with the primary key IDs created based on the records added?

Do you have any other suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: It sounds like all you need is a _query_ that selects and filters the data for your report.

Comment: And report/subreport(s) might be needed depending on table relationships.

Comment: Expanding on Gustav.  google query and access.  Then to get started make sure to set up the relationships between the tables with database tools-relationships.  Then under create choose design query or query wizard.  Add all those tables with variables you want in your report to the query.  make sure the query works then close it.  select your new query  then under create choose report.  Access will auto build the report off of the selected query.  Play around from there.